# How to add items from NSArray :

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I want to make method "additionMulti" that take n paramiters and add them in sum

My Code :

```
-(void) additionMulti:(NSArray *)data
{
    int sum=0;
    int xx;
    for(xx=0; xx < [data count]; xx++)
    {
        sum =sum + [data  objectAtIndex:xx];
    }

     NSLog(@"The result of adding %@ is : %i",data,sum);
}
```

Comment: ..and what is the problem?

Comment: So what is the problem ? Can you elaborate a bit more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to calculate the sum from an array of objects, try with this:

```
- (void)additionMulti:(NSArray *)data {
    int sum = 0;
    int xx;

    for(xx=0; xx<[data count]; xx++) {
        sum = sum + [[data objectAtIndex:xx] intValue];
    }

    NSLog(@"The result of adding %@ is : %i",data,sum);
}
```

In order to let this code works, your array must be an array of *NSNumber* or *NSString* (so you can take the intValue from each value in the array).

In case you need to add an array to an already existing array, I suggest you to follow Julian' solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the line:

```
sum = sum + [data  objectAtIndex:xx];
```

With

```
sum = sum + [[data  objectAtIndex:xx] intValue];
```

Comment: this what I relly want:

sum = sum + [[data  objectAtIndex:xx] intValue];

Comment: If your problem is solved, then please accept the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line (assuming the array is an array of NSNumbers (i.e. `NSArray * data = @[ @1.2, @3, @42 ];`).

```
NSNumber * sum = [data valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
```

For more information on the technique used (kvc-collection-operators) see this [excellent NSHipster post](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/).